# Transient inside an interface

Tags: java, interface

I have a query that below is the interface in which constants are declared , Can I also have transient here and if not then whats the reason we can not have transient varible inside an interface , I am familiar with the role of transient in serialization process..

```
 interface OlympicMedal {
  static final String GOLD = "Gold";
  static final String SILVER = "Silver";
  static final String BRONZE = "Bronze";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using enums rather than constants in an interface. The pattern you are using is common in pre java 5 code. Enums were introduced then. It introduces type safety and is the recommend way to go.

If you are serialising and want transient properties then this may help [Serializing enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586667/serializing-enums)

Answer (score 1):

All variables defined in an interface are implicitly 'static'; 'transient' is only meaningful for non-'static' fields: so what you are asking doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

All variables declared in an interface are `public`, `static` and `final`. In fact those are the only possible modifiers that are possible in an `Interface`

For the same reason, you really don't have to explicitly specify these modifiers when you're creating a variable in an `interface`. In your example, you could've just said:

```
interface OlympicMedal {
    String GOLD = "Gold";
    String SILVER = "Silver";
    String BRONZE = "Bronze";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, interface only provides a contract in terms of the operations to be defined by the classes implementing that interface. It doesn't carry state and so you cannot declare member variables in an interface (what you declared in your interface definition are constants). So, there is no possibility of a transient member in an interface.